# 3d points project 2d points error

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera, projection

I'm tried to project human skeleton 3d points to 2d points by using [`cv2.projectpoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1019495a2c8d1743ed5cc23fa0daff8c).

Here is my code:

```
tmp = np.array(data_3d['root'][i]).reshape(1,3)
revc = np.array([0, -15, -25], np.float)  # rotation vector
tvec = np.array([-2, -2, -12], np.float)  # translation vector
fx = fy = 1.0
cx = cy = 0.0
cameraMatrix = np.array([[fx, 0, cx], [0, fy, cy], [0, 0, 1]])
result = cv2.projectPoints(tmp, revc, tvec, cameraMatrix, None)
```

But I find some strange 2d points during projection.

```
root:
     X min_max=(-166.92720209469152, 1243.4813901875507)
       mean=4.290786012592475, variance=4722.3197294835645
     Y min_max=(-402.9192018458054,55.87842522603996)
       mean=0.11309526315136062, variance=499.5386080289831
head:
     X min_max=(-1757.835481879438, 425.7047344280786)
       mean=-4.077206416367477, variance=10165.268433754276
     Y min_max=(-426.06627880880535, 104.67033311809274) 
       mean=0.14534586064178603, variance=600.3554834467959
```

So I print these out

[image: root error]

and

[image: head error]

As it seems, there is some strange change.

> 40 => 80 => 190 => 425 => `-1757` => -268 => -60 => -33

My question is why this strange thing will happen?

I think it maybe occlusion at first, but `head` won't be obscured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation vector `rvec` is in radians, not degrees. Rather declare it as:

```
revc = np.rad2deg(np.array([0, -15, -25], np.float))  # rotation vector
```

Also, the focal length `fx=fx=1` is in meters, and I doubt your camera has a focal length of 1 mm. If your focal length is 1 millimeter, rather say:

```
fx = fy = .001 # in meters
```

If you need more help, rather plot those points on an image, and show us the image. This will also give you a good idea of how your projection looks. This can be done with:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(*zip(*result[0][:,0,:]))
plt.show()
```

Also, what do you mean with the following?

> As it seems, there is some strange change.
>
> 40 => 80 => 190 => 425 => -1757 => -268 => -60 => -33

Comment: Thanks! After modifying these, it's variance really decreased to normal.  About `425 => -1757 => -268`,  I want to mean 2d points x has some strange change, which leads to high variance.

Comment: It's no problem at all Lei, I'm glad I could help. Please remember to `Accept as Answer` if you want to let others know it was a helping answer (and `Upvote` if you want). Please let me know if there is something else you are struggling with.